# Cassandra cqlsh "unable to connect to any servers"

Tags: python, cassandra

I get the following message when executing cqlsh.bat on the command line

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': ProtocolError("cql_version '3.3.0' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.2.0']",)})
```

I'm running Python version 2.7.10 along with Cassandra version 2.2.1. Not sure if it's related but when I start the Cassandra server I need to run "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" on PowerShell or else it doesn't work.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can force cqlsh to use a specific cql version using the flag

> --cqlversion="#.#.#"

Example cqlsh usage (and key/values):

```
cqlsh 12.34.56.78 1234 -u username -p password --cqlversion="3.2.0"
cqlsh (IP ADDR)  (PORT)  (DB_USERN)  (DB_PASS)               (VER)
```

Answer (score 5):

edit cqlsh.py file (you can find it using `which cqlsh`) and change the value of
 `DEFAULT_CQLVER = 'z.z.z'` to the supported version.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer because it doesn't force you to pass additional parameters to cqlsh

Answer (score 3):

```
ProtocolError("cql_version '3.3.0' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.2.0']"
```

Indicates that there is a version mismatch between the C* version you are running and the python driver run by CQLSH. Make sure they are all out of the same release.

Comment: How do I find out the version of C* that I'm running?

Comment: I'm running version 2.1.9

Comment: And up above you said you are running 2.2.1 . My guess is you are using the cqlsh from 2.2.1 against 2.1.9

Comment: No Solution derived from the answer

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue when I was executing bin/cqlsh. I was seeing the below error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'cassandra-1.alpha.mimosacloud.co': ProtocolError("cql_version '3.2.0' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.2.1']",)})
```

My remote server was using cassandra 2.1.12 and I was trying to connect to it using the cqlsh bundeled with apache-cassandra-2.1.7. My problem was resolved when I downloaded apache-cassandra-2.1.12 from [this link](http://cassandra.apache.org/download/) and used the cqlsh bundled with it.

Details of my server are:
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.12 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3]