# Cassandra cqlsh Connection error : 'Unable to connect to any servers',.cql_version '3.4.0' is not supported by remote

Tags: python, database, cassandra, remote-access, cassandra-cli

I was trying to connect to my remote cassandra DB via `cqlsh` ,

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'XX.XX.XX.XX': ProtocolError("cql_version '3.4.0' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.2.1']",)})
```

I installed Planet Cassandra version 3.2.1 from this [link](http://www.planetcassandra.org/cassandra/#tablepress-3_wrapper) .

I run the command : `nodetool version` it is showing `3.2.1` version.

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002404/cassandra-cqlsh-unable-to-connect-to-any-servers) , but that didn't help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still if you want to connect over the old version you can :

```
$ cqlsh --cqlversion=3.2.1 host_ip
```

ex : `$ cqlsh --cqlversion=3.2.1 192.168.0.172`
where 192.168.0.172 is the machine where you want to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Humm, it looks like you're using an "old" version of the **cqlsh** and not the one shipped with Cassandra 3.2.1.

Try

```
shell> which cqlsh
```

or

```
shell> locate cqlsh
```

to see if it points you the the right version

Comment: Applied to me, as I have DSE cassandra and vanilla cassandra installed on same system. Commenting out the `export PATH=~/dse/bin:$PATH` in my bash_profile and reloading bash_profile solved problem and pointed to the correct `cqlsh` binary.